# How to simulate lookbehind in VBA regex?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to build a regex pattern that will return `False` if a string starts with certain characters or contains non-word characters, but because VBA's `RegExp` object doesn't support lookbehind, I am finding this difficult. The only word character prefixes that should fail are B_, B-, b_, b-.

This is my test code:

```
Sub testregex()

Dim re As New RegExp

re.pattern = "^[^Bb][^_-]\w+$"

Debug.Print re.Test("a24")
Debug.Print re.Test("a")
Debug.Print re.Test("B_")
Debug.Print re.Test(" a1")


End Sub
```

I want this to return:

```
True
True
False
False
```

but instead it returns

```
True
False
False
True
```

The problem is that the pattern looks for a character that's not in `[Bb]`, followed by a character that's not in `[-_]`, followed by a sequence of word characters, but what I want is just one or more word characters, such that if there are 2 or more characters then the first two are not `[Bb][-_]`.

Comment: In expression `" a1"` there are 2 or more characters, and the first two are not `[Bb][-_]`, but you want `.Test(" a1")` to return `False`. Following your definition it should be `True`. Please explain am I missing something?

Comment: @omegastripes, the string should only have **word characters**, which is why I used `\w` in the regex pattern.

Comment: @femtoRgon, yes, my current workaround for this involves two regexes.  I'm hoping to find a single-regex solution, as that will help with the extensibility of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try matching this expression:

```
^([Bb][\-_]\w*)|(\w*[^\w]+\w*)$
```

...which will match "B_", "b_", "B-" and "b-" or anything that's not a word character. Consider a successful match a "failure" and only allow non-matches to be valid.

Comment: While this will exclude "B_xxy", it will also exclude "B2xxy", which should pass.  The only prefixes that should fail are `B_,B-,b_,b-`.  I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear in the original question.

Comment: I adjusted the expression, though it's easiest to invert the way you think about the result such that "success" is a failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.Pattern = "^(?:[^ Bb][^ _-]\w+|[^ Bb][^ _-]|[^ Bb])$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your matches with

```
regEx.Pattern = "^[^ bB][^_ -]*\w*$"
regEx.MultiLine = True
Debug.Print regEx.Test("a24")
Debug.Print regEx.Test("a")
Debug.Print regEx.Test("B_")
Debug.Print regEx.Test(" a1")
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
False
```